# Batch file to delete files and also create the log of deleted files

Tags: batch-file

I have this code below which use to delete files and folder from drive from the particular date.....This code works fine.
Now i want to modify this code that....

i want log of all the deleted files that are deleted.....
Kindly help me to do this

```
@echo off 
 :: set folder path 

    set dump_path=E:\

 :: set min age of files and folders to delete 

    set max_days=0

:: remove files from %dump_path%

 forfiles -p %dump_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% -c "cmd /c del /q @path" 

:: remove sub directories from %dump_path%

 forfiles -p %dump_path% -d -%max_days% -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path
```

"

Comment: you can  redirect command output to a file , will that work for you ? or do you have additional cases to be met ?

Comment: i want additional case...like creating log of deleted files... @prudviraj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just extend the `cmd` executed, eg. like this:

```
"cmd /c del /q @path && echo @path>>logfile.log"
```

Bonus: This will actually only log the file name if the `del` has succeeded.

```
"cmd /c del /q @path && echo @path>>logfile.log || echo @path>>logfile.err"
```

will additionally log any failed deletes.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Bonus code supplied above, `"cmd /c del /q @path && echo @path>>logfile.log || echo @path>>logfile.err"` but found that it wrote all output whether successful or not to both locations. I also had to change the || to | for it to work.

I did find that using this code `2>>c:\users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\LogFile.err` wrote only the failed attempts, as this pipes out the STDERR instead of the STDOUT by using the 2>, I've used 2>> so that it ammends the file instead of outputting one line only (logging just the one error)